# Redirecting part of function is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am using the following function to automatically replace the product in the cart if the user adds another product. Its working perfectly.
I am trying to add a redirect to checkout after the product has been replaced. But the redirect does not work as I wish.

```
function custom_maybe_empty_cart( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) {
        
        if( ! empty ( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) && $valid ){
                WC()->cart->empty_cart();
              wc_add_notice( 'Only allowed 1 item in cart.', 'error' );
               }
        return $valid;
        wp_redirect( 'https://ils.semarient.io/commander' );
        exit;
        
  }

  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_maybe_empty_cart', 10, 3 );
```

I've tried different placements for the following lines :

```
wp_redirect( 'https://ils.semarient.io/commander' );
            exit;
```

1 ) after the wc_add_notice : nothing happens
2 ) after teturn $valid : nothing happens
3 ) after final brace (before add filter) : endlessly loops to redirect to the page I want and ends in a page crash (too many redirects) > means the redirect is working then ? but isn't at the right place...
Code is in the function.php file from child theme

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: The `return` statement stops the execution of the function and returns the value, so nothing after a `return` will be executed. And if you put it inside the `if`-statement, it will only be executed when the if-statement validates as true.

Comment: Another possible issue would be if this code is called in an Ajax request. When you make an Ajax request, it will ignore any "redirect" headers it get from the server. In those cases, you need to do the redirection in the success-callback for the Ajax request (which are all in your JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks @M.Eriksson, appreciate the help. Since the code is as it is (no extra wrapper) in the function.php file from child theme, then it is not called in a Ajax request I guess. Wondering where to put those lines.

Comment: I wouldn't count it out, but it's pretty easy to find out. When you add a product to the cart, does the page reload or does it happen "in the background"?

Comment: yes, the page reloads when i add the product.